# ASP.NET - Setting CssClass of a CheckBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The following code

```
((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("exportCb")).CssClass = "enabledExport";
```

Creates html

```
<span class="enabledExport"><input id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridviewName__ctl2_exportCb" type="checkbox" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:gridviewName:_ctl2:exportCb" /></span>
```

For the asp.net gridview column

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Export">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="exportCb"/>        
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle/>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I need to use jquery

```
$('.enabledExport').toggle()
```

to check/uncheck (as a toggle) the checkboxes.  Because the `CssClass` is marked on the `<span>` the code is going to try to toggle a `<span>` instead of the `<input>`.  How can I fix this?

I don't mind if the solution is on jquery or asp.net side as long as it works.  I'd love it if the code just marked the input like its supposed to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to show/hide the checkbox you could do this:

```
$('.enabledExport input:checkbox').toggle()
```

but what I think you're trying to do is:

```
var $checkbox = $('.enabledExport input:checkbox');
$checkbox.attr("checked", !$checkbox.is(":checked"));
```

Comment: +1 @hunter yes you are correct.  Toggle is incorrect.  I need to do the second one.  Though, its not working.  I'm playing with it (I may need to add $.each, but at least one should work :\)...still working on it.  Does this form of select work even though my span is marked instead of the input?

Comment: master page didnt import my jquery scripts.  Moved it into child page and now my jquery works.  So do this solution.  Thanks!

Comment: That is odd how toggle - toggles the visibility of a checkbox.  Seems like a bad default IMO.

Comment: `toggle()` applies more globally for visibility to all elements so that's probably why. In the past I would always have some toggling method that did the show/hide so it felt right to me.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to design jQuery selector in such way, that it would select checkbox that is located as a child of span with class 'enabledExport'.
In this case it would look like:

```
jQuery('.enabledCheckbox > :checkbox').toggle()
```

or

```
jQuery(':checkbox', '.enabledCheckbox').toggle()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct cssclass and prefix it with a dot. So you've selected your span.
Then step into that span and select the checkbox. This is to bind the click event:

```
$(".enabledExport").click(function(){
  var box = $(this).children(":checkbox");
  box.is(":checked") ? box.removeAttr("checked") : box.attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

And this is clicking:

```
$(".enabledExport").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a MasterSite page so the checkbox elements id is getting the ContentPlaceHolder information added to the checkbox id.  When the page loads, I am assigning a custom attribute to help find the elements (can be done with a foreach statement also).  Here is the custom attribute code behind:

> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> {
>
> ```
>   if (!IsPostBack)
>    {
>       chkTxa.Attributes.Add("clientID", "chkTxa");
>       chkTxx.Attributes.Add("clientID", "chkTxx");
>    }
> ```
>
> }

My two checkbox IDs are: chkTxa and chkTxx.  I set the AutoPostBack="False" because I want the client side to take care of the checkbox toggling.  Since the checkbox is located within an html table, the browser is wrapping the checkbox in a  tag.  This requires you to do extra work to find the checkbox.  The jQuery code is this:

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> ```
>     var chkTxa;
>     var chkTxx;
>     // dig into the <span> object to find the checkbox
>     chkTxa = $("[clientID=chkTxa]").children(":checkbox");
>     chkTxx = $("[clientID=chkTxx]").children(":checkbox");
>
>     $(chkTxa).click(function () {
>         if (!chkTxa.is(":checked")) {
>             chkTxa.removeAttr("checked");
>         }
>         else {
>             chkTxx.removeAttr("checked");
>         }
>     });
>
>    $(chkTxx).click(function () {
>         if (!chkTxx.is(":checked")) {
>             chkTxx.removeAttr("checked");
>         }
>         else {
>             chkTxa.removeAttr("checked");
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

Hopefully someone finds this useful.

Allen

Answer (score 0):

`$(".enabledExport+input").toggle()` should do the trick.