# handle checkbox with class selector

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a `<asp:Checkbox />` and I want to see whether it's checked or not via jQuery. Problem is, it always returns false. Does it have to do with the fact that I'm selecting the element via class?

**The js**

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

var map;

function initialize() {

    var x;
    x = $(".chkSetMap");
    x.click(setMap);
}

function setMap() {

    if ($('.chkSetMap').attr('checked') == true) {
        $(".comboMap").attr("disabled", true);

    }
}
```

**the checkbox**

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSetMap" CssClass="chkSetMap" runat="server" />
```

**the checkbox rendered**

```
<span class="chkSetMap"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkSetMap" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkSetMap" /></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `.is()` method and the `:checked` shorthand selector

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

var $chkSetMap;

function initialize() {
    $chkSetMap = $(".chkSetMap input:checkbox").click(setMap);
}

function setMap() {
    $(".comboMap").attr("disabled", $chkSetMap.is(':checked'));
}
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/5XA7D/ **UPDATED!**

---

Since ASP.Net server controls are awesome it's wrapping your checkbox in a `span`. The `span` has the `chkSetMap` class, not the checkbox.

Comment: @Chad it's on the DOM, which does work like that. It's not setting the attribute to a string, it's setting it to a boolean

Comment: a simple "yes you misunderstood" would have sufficed.

Comment: @Chad yes, you misunderstand. You can explicitly set "disabled" to true or false, respectively. Works with checkboxes checked state as well. What you're thinking of is `attr("disabled", "disabled")` or `removeAttr("disabled")`

Comment: @Jorge see the example in my answer

Comment: @Chad - no worries, didn't mean to offend, but I was writing that example up anyway.

Comment: @hunter i tried but don't work i think that problem it´s that check is asp and not html

Comment: @Jorge - in the end they're one in the same. What ASP.Net ends up rendering is just HTML. Can you post some of your rendered HTML? Are there more than one checkboxes with that class on the page?

Comment: @hunter sure give me one second

Comment: @Jorge - hah, just answered another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115198/asp-net-setting-cssclass-of-a-checkbox/6115243#6115243 and your solution is similar. Updating my answer/ example

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET puts the `CssClass` on a `<span>` (which is where any `Text` would go). So, your selector picks up the `<span>`.

Try using the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to get to the checkbox: `$('.chkSetMap > input:checkbox')`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have an anonymous function. (#content is wjhatever div is the div on your page that has all the   inputs you're looking for in it). This function will disable ALL of the dropdowns of .comboMap class if ANY of the checkboxes of chkSetMap is checked.
If you only have 1 checkbox and one select - use IDs instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {
    $('.chkSetMap').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#content").find('.comboMap').attr("disabled", true);
        }else{
        $("#content").find('.comboMap').attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });

});
});
```